# Wordpress: redirect all 404's from one directory to index page of that directory

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-404

There are some Wordpress plugins for permanent redirection of all 404's to the main blog URL (plugin '404 Redirection') or all 404's to one specified page (plugin '404-to-start').

Also, it can be done by adding following code to the theme's 404.php page.

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url'));
exit();
?>
```

I need to redirect all 404's from one directory to index page of that directory. Does anybody know how this can be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tempalte - 404.php

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'/');
exit();
?>
```